Unable to access external drive 24.4
I had been using an external drive to watch movies and was working fine. I then used another external drive and that too worked. However, when I changed back to the first one, I got an Unable to mount error message and I'm unable to access the drive:

Error mounting /dev/SCB1 at/media/David/Seagate: wrong fs type, bad option, bad super lock on /dev/sdb1, missing code page or helper program, or other error

Since the first drive used to work before, what's the problem?

I don't think so as this hdd was working the last time i connected it but i will check the formating on my pc. OK Weird, I connected the HDD to my windows pc. I got an error message that the drive had errors and needed witndows to fix. I carried out the fixes and then connected it to my Ubuntu system and it worked.

Please post your comment as an answer to your own question so that other Ask Ubuntu users can benefit from your experience solving your problem.

This question is similar to: Can't access windows 10 partition after update to 23.10. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ok fixed. Someone suggested that I should check the formatting. So I connected the drive to my Windows laptop and got the error message that the drive needed scanning and repairing.
I followed through on that with Windows scan and repair. When I went back to Ubuntu system again and the drive was mounted successfully.

Your question should have had the details that it was a dual boot system. If Windows has been accessing the drive it can be left in an unstable state after. This issue might arise again if you Windows does not cleanly exit the drive.

No it doesn't have a duel boot. It was a fresh total install. I used my PC

@Arjun K Shibu's answer in Can't access windows 10 partition after update to 23.10 gave good result:

This problem usually occurs due to bad clusters, dirty states, or due to a missing helper program.
The basic fix for missing helper program is to install the following:
sudo apt install nfs-common
sudo apt install cifs-utils

Still, if you are unable to fix the problem, ntfsfix might help fix the partition. The ntfs-3g package contains the ntfsfix utility (which usually comes preinstalled). If not, you can install it using:
sudo apt install ntfs-3g

Then try to fix the partition by running the following command:
sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sdxx

The -b flag tries to fix bad clusters and -d to fix dirty states. In the above command you have to change the sdxx partition based on your system.
In your particular case, the 634 GB Volume is /dev/sdb1 as displayed in the screenshot you provided, so the command you should run is:
sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sdb1

Hope it helps!


ntfsfix isn't 'a full solution like MSFT chkdsk is, so it is STILL advised to keep a windows system around to repair NTFS partitions, even if the 'repair disk' is just a Windows installer disk booted to repair mode to allow access to command line and to manually run chkdisk.

Thanks. I have Windows/Ubuntu Studio. Windows has checked the drive a few times without finding faults, Ubuntu did find a fault and repaired it. The USB drive is used to back up stuff.

I dual boot in Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows. I had a very similar problem with a 1TB Samsung NVMe external USB drive after updating to Ubuntu 24.04.1. I have a Lenovo T14s Gen 4 AMD laptop. It worked OK sometimes, sometimes I could not mount or access it, but it was seen by Ubuntu.
I read that there are some problems with the ntfs "driver" in Ubuntu, causing problems with the ntfs file system, and that the recommended solution was to disable the current version of the driver in Ubuntu as a workaround to prevent this problem from reoccurring. This is done by creating a file by this command in terminal:
echo 'blacklist ntfs3' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/disable-ntfs3.conf

Then reboot. This forces Ubuntu to use the older, reliably working ntfs driver. When the problem is eventually solved in Ubuntu, this workaround should be easily reversed by deleting the disable-ntfs3.conf file just created in /etc/modprobe.d/ with the above command.
I also booted into Windows and inserted the drive to check and fix if there was problems with the file system on it (just because it was easier for me at the time, the same can be done in Ubuntu). Windows did some quick fix automatically when inserting the drive.
The external drive has been working fine in Ubuntu since.
